# Freeing up space from MyISAM table after deleting data

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a MyISAM table that I deleted 21.7GB worth of rows from, but of course the space is still not freed to the hard drive. I have read about the OPTIMIZE TABLE command, however unfortunately I only have 17GB available on my server and my understanding is that the file is duplicated before being freed, which can't happen without the 22GB free.

This table is no longer going to be used. This space will never be naturally reclaimed so there is no reason to keep it there and I would like to reclaim it. The rest of the DB it is in is still in use though. Is there any way to really free the space, or get the DB to allocate this space in another table still in use?

(it would be possible I guess to change my code to use this table instead of another one, thus using this free space, but I would prefer not to have to resort to that)

Comment: Dropping the table should remove the files that contain the table data, which should reclaim the space.

Comment: Thanks. There is still a small amount of data in the table. If I copy this to a new table, then delete the old one, would this work?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: It worked. If you post it as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the remaining data to a new table, then drop the old table. That will reclaim the storage.